# Ionic android push notification works only in background

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification

I'm building an Ionic App which uses push notifications. I followed the documentation from [here](https://apps.ionic.io) . I can register, I see the token is registered OK, but when I send notifications from [ionic](https://apps.ionic.io), I receive them only if the app is in background. If the app is running, I get no notification . The event `cloud:push:notification` is not triggered.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: I've got the exact same issue.  I can register the token, but I don't receive any notifications.  Any luck yet?

Comment: @mtpultz I switched back to $cordovaPushV5, and is working ok for now

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the `ionic-cloud` library for interfacing with Ionic.io. The event you mentioned is not triggered by the deprecated `ionic-platform-web-clinet`

http://docs.ionic.io/migration.html#push`

Comment: Thanks for response!I user ionic-cloud and  I completely removed ionic-platform-web-client, but still the same...

Comment: I'm using ionic-cloud's $ionicPush on a new project (so not migrating) and I've followed the docs with no luck receiving a notification either, but I can see I am registering the token, and it looks like this is a problem many are having on the forum, but no solutions.  The Ionic Cloud service seems too new to have any tutorials.

Comment: Looks like new projects have to enable FCM and not GCM now